# Multiple questions in one post

Tags: discussion

We have [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/ultimaker-cura-problems-with-build-platform-size-and-overhang-support) question where it was flagged that the question has too many questions in it. I am not seeing anywhere that states that it is not allowed. Other than risking making the question too broad. I thought it was an interesting topic so I am moving the discussion out of comments and into here.

Multiple questions is discouraged in the [how to ask good questions guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ...

> require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request
>   answers to multiple questions.

but I cannot find a rule saying it's not allowed (so long as it's not considered broad).

Comment: Is the "SO" a typo? I'd assume that to mean "Stack Overflow", but obviously it's our question we're talking about here.

Comment: Yes I mean stack overflow question. Which is probably redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Two questions that are not related should not be grouped together in a "single question" format. Maybe it is not forbidden, but certainly not a logical thing to do.

We should encourage people not to post multiple questions as

- this makes it more difficult to answer as there are multiple answers, and
- we also need more questions.

Furthermore, it is probably also easier to find (when they are separated), either through the site search or through Google.

In the specific case you mention, the common denominator is the use of Ultimaker Cura, but a print bed size question and a question on support should not be together in a "single question". Furthermore, his second question is pretty unclear, it is not specified what the actual problems with the red areas are, there is no mentioning of a failed print. Discussion in comments has been avoided to clear that up.

Comment: Yeah I am all for encouraging them to do better. Though as an Admin and I have flags for a post like this, there's not much I think I should do. I do not think we want to close questions such as this. Though I could see doing that for a more extreme case. This one second question was a minor topic. But if the post was I have this issue with an extruder and this Cad question, then we likely should close.